# Did Cummings' editors try to fix his works' eccentricities?

Tags: textual-history, orthography, e-e-cummings

E.E. Cummings often wrote with deliberately unconventional spelling and syntax. It was popularly criticised when published; however, did his editors try to "fix" his work *before* it was published?

If not, how did Cummings convey his intentions to the editors? If so, did they know about his intent and disagree?

Comment: http://68.media.tumblr.com/b0f2429bc8622c4c2869ef6c98a5813f/tumblr_nzizy7RdR61urz4z1o1_1280.jpg

Comment: [This interesting article](http://faculty.gvsu.edu/websterm/cummings/caps.htm) touches on a related issue - the capitalisation (or not) of his name. I haven't found anything more general though.

Answer (score 11):

They cut his work a lot, and he couldn't do much about it.

His first book of poetry, Tulips and Chimneys (T&C), was especially edited. The original manuscript contained 152 poems, but only 86 were actually published in the books. The others were published two years later in 1925 under the title '&' - Cummings wanted the original book to be titled 'Tulips & Chimneys (with an ampersand)' but was overruled by his editor - Thomas Seltzer. Thomas changed the title to just Tulips and Chimneys, and then published the later poems under the title & (changing 'ampersand' to just 'and')

When Cummings reviewed the cut-down T&C, he was unhappy. However, he conceded, but insisted that the original order of the poems was kept.

So in answer to your question - yes, they knew about his intent and disagreed. I assume thy had conversations about it though.

Sources: [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E._E._Cummings), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tulips_and_Chimneys), [3](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems-and-poets/poets/detail/e-e-cummings) and [4](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=GxIBDQAAQBAJ&pg=PA130&lpg=PA130&dq=Tulips+and+Chimneys+editor+cuts&source=bl&ots=QabiC24fZc&sig=ZwjKrsApXWS_8p0Ep_c0XxxPa5Y&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjz28jRnO3RAhUOOsAKHSldAjQQ6AEIITAB#v=onepage&q=cuts&f=false)